# What is the best export of a 3D model?

Tags: modeling

I see FBX is probably the most universally accepted, but what is the one that keeps the most quality between applications?

Examples: .fbx, .bvh, .dae, .cr2, .mi, .c4d, .obj, .blend, .u3d, .mdd (i understand that some of these are application specific)

Comment: It'll depend on what you kind of data want to export and which program you are exporting to. Unfortunately 3D formats seem to suffer from an excess of standards, resulting in a lot of different formats and programs which all handle them differently.

Comment: As gandalf3 said, it depends on the app you want to export to. If you want to export to another modern 3D program, there's a good chance you'll get good results with Collada (.dae), a format that was developed specifically to enable maximal compatibility between different apps. That's my personal experience anyway...